# Unable to deploy Tornado with nginx reverse proxy, no errors are displayed

Tags: python, nginx, proxy, tornado

I am trying to deploy my Tornado app with Nginx as proxy. I am trying to run this on Ramnode VPS (512 CVZ) whose configuration is:

- 512MB RAM
- 512MB VSwap
- 2 CPU Core Access
- 120GB SSD-Cached HDD Space
- 1Gbps Port

I am not using supervisor as of now and I manually started four instances of my tornado process:

```
sudo python /home/magneto/pricechase/main.py --port=8000 &
sudo python /home/magneto/pricechase/main.py --port=8001 &
sudo python /home/magneto/pricechase/main.py --port=8002 &
sudo python /home/magneto/pricechase/main.py --port=8003 &
```

and I can access the site now at pricechase.in:8000 to pricechase.in:8003

I created a new user `nginx` and gave permissions to my project directory:

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --disabled-password --group nginx
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /home/magneto/pricechase/
```

Following is the conf file for my project, located at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pricechase.in`

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 5;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll; 
}

http{

    proxy_next_upstream error;

    upstream tornadoes { 
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;
        server 127.0.0.1:8002;
        server 127.0.0.1:8003;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;  

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    proxy_read_timeout 200;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css text/xml
               application/x-javascript application/xml
               application/atom+xml text/javascript;


    server { 
        listen 80;
        server_name pricechase.in www.pricechase.in;

        location /static/ {
            root /home/magneto/pricechase/static; 
            if ($query_string) {
                expires max; 
            }
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server; 
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme; 
            proxy_pass http://tornadoes;
        } 
    }
}
```

When I tried to restart nginx service I was getting following error:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "user" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pricechase.in:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

As the answers indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751455/configuration-fail-nginx-setting-for-tornadoweb-unknown-directive-user), I commented the following line in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
# include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Now I can start/restart it however when I type in pricechase.in, its not opening the site. Its not able to access static files also, ex: http://pricechase.in/static/css/tooltipster.css which is located at `/home/magneto/pricechase/static/css/tooltipster.css`

Following is the contents of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pricechase.in;
}
```

- How do I debug this?
- Why its not logging any errors? I checked access and error logs (located in `/var/log/nginx/`)
- Any tips/improvements on nginx config files?
- If I understand correctly `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is like a base template and all the common config I require for any other hosts should be included in this, right?
- If I want to add another domain and serve different tornado instances, I guess I have to add new conf in `sites-enabled`, however will there be any conflict? for example, I want http://abc.xyz.com to serve static content located in `/home/magneto/blog` and http://pqrs.com to serve tornado process of ports 8005 to 8008.

Comment: I moved `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pricechase.in` to `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and its working as expected. Not sure if thats what I should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A config fragment in sites-enabled should only include the part inside the "http" block; the other parts can only appear at the top-level nginx.conf.